# how to deploy nodejs on heroku

Tags: node.js, angularjs, heroku, gruntjs

Hi I developed a small application in nodeJs and angular using the angular-fullstack generator for grunt, following the instruction on:  https://npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-fullstack, when I finished the developement run:

> ```
> 3) yo angular-fullstack:deploy heroku
>  4) cd heroku && git push heroku master
> ```

my application  now is on heroku and the dynos starts, but when I visit the domain where  heroku put my application: http://dollsdresses-gnosis.herokuapp.com/
I can see that some files are missing: main.css, script.js , all I can see is a white page with my favicon, when I use my application on my computer, running: grunt server, it works, so I think there is something that I do not know or do wrong on deploying  on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have added `main.css`, `script.js` et al to git, so they are not pushed to Heroku when you run `git push heroku master`. Make sure to `git add` them.

Comment: thanks, but the problem maybe is in some settings of the  generator angular-fullstack because it produced those files some where